# Quikfixj unable to read logon message in Initiator

Tags: quickfixj

My application is sending logon request and getting logon response and session get logged in perfectly at first time . After some time session get disconnected due to heartbeat timeout and my application send login again and acceptor send login response within same second but my initiator don't get connected after 10 second it send another login request. Ideally it should not send login request again.

Event logs are

```
20181015-13:36:34: Sent test request TEST
20181015-13:37:01: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for heartbeat
20181015-13:37:02: Initiated logon request
20181015-13:37:13: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response
20181015-13:37:32: Disconnecting: Socket exception (/192.168.40.29:31815): java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
20181015-13:38:02: Initiated logon request
```

Message logs

```
8=FIX.4.2^A9=69^A35=A^A34=1064^A49=test^A52=20181015-13:37:02.570^A56=test^A98=0^A108=30^A10=075^A
8=FIX.4.2^A9=000593^A35=A^A34=001527^A43=N^A52=20181015-13:37:02^A49=test^A56=test^A98=0^A108=30^A6247=prod^A6272=AMEX/OPT,CBOE/OPT,PHLX/OPT,PSE/OPT,DTB/OPT,ISE/OPT,BELFOX/OPT,GLOBEX/FOP,MONEP/OPT,SOFFEX/OPT,FTA/OPT,ASX/OPT,BOX/OPT,ECBOT/FOP,IBCX/BAG,BATS/OPT,NASDAQOM/OPT,ICEEU/OPT^A6382=S3^A6387=s3.amazonaws.com^A6386=0WWXP5X5ZAMQC93NZR82^A6492=1^A6541=1^A6530=1^A6550=1^A6560=1/Maximize Rebate,9/Prefer Rebate,11/Prefer Fill,12/Maximize Fill,2/Primary Exchange,3/Highest Volume Exchange With Rebate,4/High Volume Exchange With Lowest Fee^A6749=1/Maximize Rebate,9/Prefer Rebate,11/Prefer Fill,12/Maximize Fill^A8035=5bc41694.^A10=210^A
8=FIX.4.2^A9=69^A35=A^A34=1065^A49=test^A52=20181015-13:38:02.569^A56=test^A98=0^A108=30^A10=085^A
8=FIX.4.2^A9=000593^A35=A^A34=001528^A43=N^A52=20181015-13:38:02^A49=test^A56=test^A98=0^A108=30^A6247=prod^A6272=AMEX/OPT,CBOE/OPT,PHLX/OPT,PSE/OPT,DTB/OPT,ISE/OPT,BELFOX/OPT,GLOBEX/FOP,MONEP/OPT,SOFFEX/OPT,FTA/OPT,ASX/OPT,BOX/OPT,ECBOT/FOP,IBCX/BAG,BATS/OPT,NASDAQOM/OPT,ICEEU/OPT^A6382=S3^A6387=s3.amazonaws.com^A6386=0WWXP5X5ZAMQC93NZR82^A6492=1^A6541=1^A6530=1^A6550=1^A6560=1/Maximize Rebate,9/Prefer Rebate,11/Prefer Fill,12/Maximize Fill,2/Primary Exchange,3/Highest Volume Exchange With Rebate,4/High Volume Exchange With Lowest Fee^A6749=1/Maximize Rebate,9/Prefer Rebate,11/Prefer Fill,12/Maximize Fill^A8035=5bc41694.^A10=212^A
```

I have removed actual SendercompId and Target comp Id

As you can see we send login request at 20181015-13:37:02.570 and get response at 20181015-13:37:02 then still it send one more login request.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What version of QuickFIX/J are you using? Also, SO may not be the perfect place to ask a question about this sort of problem. Better would to use the [QuickFIX/J SourceForge user list](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quickfixj/lists/quickfixj-users) which can deal with this better. If even they cannot help you, try [QuickFIX/J support](https://www.quickfixj.org/support/).

Comment: I am using 1.5.3

Comment: Late comment: I was running both the connectors and acceptors on the same application and had them connect to each other for test purposes. I was manually starting the initiators and observed the error you described above. When I switched to ThreadedSocketInitiator then the logon worked successfully. Not sure what caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: did you solve the issue? i am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Quickfix internally send logon request when we call initiator start method, until it gets the logon response from the server. And make sure you have latest version of quickfix.

Note: If you send username and password while login to the server, check the msg type logon in ToAdmin method.

Happy coding!!